# Laravel JSON parsing issue in blade

Tags: javascript, json, laravel, laravel-blade

While assigning JSON in blade produces a JavaScript syntax error. There is two different cases:

**First Case**

```
var jsonString = {!! $json !!}; //it produce syntax error
```

It produce syntax error in some cases

**Second Case**

```
 var jsonString = JSON.parse("{!! $json !!}");
```

It produce error while null or empty

> Unexpected end of JSON input

Is there any way that handle both situations?

Comment: var jsonString : {!! json_encode($json) !!}, where $json is an array. This format is form blade. when u want to use the same in javascript,var jsonString = jsonString;

Answer (score 2):

```
 var jsonString = JSON.parse("{!! json_encode($json) !!}");
```

It is working for me.

Comment: It's already json string so `json_encode` will throw an exception

Comment: It wont throw any error i am using this and its working fine for me. The error which you were getting was the same error which i got than i used like this and it runs fine.

Comment: Agree, It'll array in your case.

Comment: Yes we don't need to parse also

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this -

```
var json_res = "{{$json}}";
var jsonString = JSON.parse(json_res);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I think its same as `JSON.parse("{!! $json !!}")`

Comment: please check the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using this way:

```
var json = null;

try {
    var json = JSON.parse('<?=str_replace('\'','\\\'', $json);?>');
} catch(SyntaxError) {
    // Do something If the json string is not a valid json.
}
```